# Finding java.lang.ClassCastException on this program, can someone help me?

Tags: java, classcastexception

I'm writing a code for a graph that is able to map down a city based on ids and I'm having this error pop off when I search for the successors of a vertex. Can someone help me pls?

The exact problem is occurring in the DataStructure class but I decided I'd post the whole code just if you see an error where I don't.

This is the error I'm getting:

> ```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to
>     class Node (java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader
>     'bootstrap'; Node is in unnamed module of loader
>     java.net.URLClassLoader @3df5c641)
>   at DataStructure.getSuccessors(DataStructure.java:19)
>   at Main.main(Main.java:18)
> ```

Thanks in advance everyone!

This is the code I have:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main() {
        DataRead d = new DataRead();
        HashMap<Long, Node> vertex = d.readVertex();
        System.out.println(vertex.size());
        ArrayList<Triplet<Long, Long, Double>> edges = d.readEdges();
        System.out.println(edges.size());
        DataStructure e = new DataStructure(vertex, edges);
        System.out.println(e.adjGraph.size());
        System.out.println(vertex.get(new Long(287291920)).id);

        Long l = new Long(287291920);
        Long l2 = new Long(1397149003);

        ArrayList<Long> test1 = e.getSuccessors(l);
        System.out.println(test1.size());

        for(Long i : test1) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Distance: " + e.getDistance(l, l2));
    }
}

public class Node {    
    Long id;

    public Node(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Triplet<a, b, c> {

    private final a first;
    private final b second;
    private final c dist;

    public Triplet(a first, b second, c dist) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.dist = dist;
    }

    public a getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public b getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public c getDistance() {
        return dist;
    }
}

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Object;

public class DataRead {
    public HashMap<Long, Node> readVertex() {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        HashMap<Long, Node> vertex = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Vertices.txt"));
            String line;
            int count = 0;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = line.split(" ");
                Long id = Long.parseLong(arr[0]);
                Node v = new Node(id);
                vertex.put(v.id, v);
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e)  {
            System.out.println("Your file couldn't be found");
        }

        return vertex;
    }
    public ArrayList<Triplet<Long, Long, Double>> readEdges() {
        ArrayList<Triplet<Long, Long, Double>> edges = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Arcos.txt"));
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = line.split(" ");
                Long origin = Long.parseLong(arr[0]);
                Long destination = Long.parseLong(arr[1]);
                Double dist = Double.parseDouble(arr[2]);
                Triplet<Long, Long, Double> t = new Triplet(origin, destination, dist);
                edges.add(t);
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e)  {
            System.out.println("Your file couldn't be found");
        }

        return edges;
    }
}

import java.util.*;

public class DataStructure {

    ArrayList<Triplet<Node, Node, Double>> adjGraph = new ArrayList<>();

    public DataStructure (HashMap<Long, Node> vertex, ArrayList<Triplet<Long, Long, Double>> edges) {
        for(Triplet<Long, Long, Double> t : edges) {
            Triplet<Node, Node, Double> triplet = new Triplet(t.getFirst(), t.getSecond(), t.getDistance());
            adjGraph.add(triplet);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Long> getSuccessors (Long Vid) {
        ArrayList<Long> successors = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < adjGraph.size(); i++) {
            Triplet<Node, Node, Double> t = adjGraph.get(i);
            if(Vid == adjGraph.get(i).getFirst().id) {
                successors.add(adjGraph.get(i).getSecond().id);
            }
        }

        return successors;
    }

    public Double getDistance(Long sourceID, Long destinationID){
        for(int i=0; i < adjGraph.size(); i++){
            if((sourceID == adjGraph.get(i).getFirst().id) && (destinationID == adjGraph.get(i).getSecond().id)){
                return adjGraph.get(i).getDistance();
            }
        }
        return -1.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the exception and stacktrace to help troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Just did! Sorry for the beginner's mistake

Comment: What does vertices.txt look like?

Comment: vertices.txt has the id for each node and other variables that are unnecessary. arcos.txt shows the connections between nodes and the distance between them

Comment: @PedroBotero your directly converting type(Long) to Node you can try this Triplet<Node, Node, Double> triplet = new Triplet<Node, Node, Double>(new Node(t.getFirst()), new Node(t.getSecond()), t.getDistance());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have some unchecked conversions in your code:

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked *.java
DataRead.java:41: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to Triplet(a,b,c) as a member of the raw type Triplet
                Triplet<Long, Long, Double> t = new Triplet(origin, destination, dist);
                                                ^
  where a,b,c are type-variables:
    a extends Object declared in class Triplet
    b extends Object declared in class Triplet
    c extends Object declared in class Triplet
DataRead.java:41: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
                Triplet<Long, Long, Double> t = new Triplet(origin, destination, dist);
                                                ^
  required: Triplet<Long,Long,Double>
  found:    Triplet
DataStructure.java:9: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to Triplet(a,b,c) as a member of the raw type Triplet
            Triplet<Node, Node, Double> triplet = new Triplet(t.getFirst(), t.getSecond(), t.getDistance());
                                                  ^
  where a,b,c are type-variables:
    a extends Object declared in class Triplet
    b extends Object declared in class Triplet
    c extends Object declared in class Triplet
DataStructure.java:9: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            Triplet<Node, Node, Double> triplet = new Triplet(t.getFirst(), t.getSecond(), t.getDistance());
                                                  ^
  required: Triplet<Node,Node,Double>
  found:    Triplet
Note: Main.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 warnings
```

These are causing "heap pollution" where you end up with a value of the wrong type in one of the fields of one of your generic classes.

I think I can see what the actual problem, but *since this is your homework* I will leave it to you to read the compilation warnings above and figure out what you have done wrong.

(Hint: you are using `Triplet` inconsistently ...)

The lesson here is that you should NOT ignore the compiler warnings about unchecked conversions, etc when you are using generic types.  The compiler is basically saying "I don't know if this is correct".  And if the code is incorrect, you will get an class cast exception at runtime at an unexpected place.